# Tools for practicing with monitors and semaphores

Tags: c++, c, concurrency, semaphore, monitor

I'm a student of a course in operating systems and i want do exercises with semaphores and monitors. Bearing in mind that my favourite programming language is C/C++, is there a good library, which includes monitors and semaphores constructs, to do my work?